# How to have Gmail reply with a document when I receive an email to a specific address?

Tags: gmail

I use Gmail to collect mail from several addresses.

I would to set up an address whose only purpose is to reply with a copy of my CV / resume (and, possibly a covering letter).

Can it be done? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'm oversimplifying and copy/pasting, but here's the general concept.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/apps-script

### Write a Google Apps Script

Open Google Drive in your web browser.
Click New > More > Google Apps Script.
Start a blank project.
Create a script according to the example, with these functions:

**startSchedule**: Code to begin running checkMail every hour: Gmail.Users.newTrigger("checkMail").timeBased().everyHours(1).create();

**checkMail**: Code to look for new emails, and if received call the next function

**mailMyResume**: Send an email with your resume attached, to the email address provided as an argument

### Turn on the Gmail API and start the Schedule

In the Apps Script editor, click Resources > Advanced Google Services.

Locate Gmail API in the dialog and click the corresponding toggle, setting it to on.

Click the Google Developers Console link.

Enter "Gmail API" into the search box and click on the corresponding entry in the results.

Click the Enable API button.

Return to the Apps Script editor and click the OK button on the Advanced Google Services dialog.

In the Apps Script editor, click Run > listLabels.

The first time you run the sample, it will prompt you to authorize access.

Click the Continue button.

Click the Accept button.

To view the script's output, click View > Logs.

### IFTTT

If the coding doesn't sound like fun, see if IFTTT has a solution: https://ifttt.com/gmail